# How should I cast a value (not a pointer) to a subclass without using a constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, casting

I have the following classes intended to be used as value types (since they only store an integer):

```
class _foo_t
{
    friend _foo_t _make_foo();
private:
    int foo;
    _foo_t(int foo) : foo(foo) {}
protected:
    void *getptr() const; // defined in .cpp
};

template <typename T>
class foo_t : public _foo_t
{
public:
    T *getptr() const { return (T*)_foo_t::getptr(); }
    T &getref() const { return *(T*)_foo_t::getptr(); }
};

_foo_t _make_foo(); // defined in .cpp

template <typename T>
foo_t<T> make_foo()
{
    return _make_foo(); // What kind of cast do I need here?
}
```

The class `foo_t<T>` is just a wrapper around `_foo_t` that provides type safety for the `getptr` and `getref` member functions. Likewise, the function `make_foo()` is just a wrapper around `_make_foo<T>()`. Since `foo_t<T>` is a subclass of `_foo_t` and does not add any fields and there are no virtual members, a `foo_t<T>` object should look exactly the same as a `_foo_t` object in memory, and I do not not want the overhead of a constructor call here. How can I cast the return value of `_make_foo()` from `_foo_t` to `foo_t<T>` safely, compliantly, and without creating any overhead?

EDIT:

Per request, here is some sample usage of the above:

```
class SomeObject { /* ... */ };

foo_t<SomeObject> obj = make_foo<SomeObject>();

new (obj.getptr()) SomeObject();
obj.getref().doSomething();
```

In reality, `make_foo` would have to take a size parameter or something.

Comment: If you're only storing integers, why do you need such complicated scaffolding? However if you want type erasure over value types you typically use Variant or Union types.

Comment: @MorphingDragon: That's not important to the question, but if you want to know, the integers are really pointers to a virtual memory map, and I want typesafe dereferencing (in reality, I'm using `operator*` and such rather than `getref` and `getptr`).

Comment: see my comment edit.

Comment: Can you post sample code that makes use of `foo_t` and `make_foo()`?

Comment: @MorphingDragon: How would I do that in a non-convoluted way?

Comment: @Matt If I'm understanding the intend for your code correctly, use composition instead of inheritance. Have foo_t<T> contain a _foo_t and delegate any relevant method calls to it.

Comment: @MorphingDragon: How does that solve any of the problems I mentioned?

Comment: @Matt you box the general type in a more specific type, in this case you should be able to eliminate any need for casting a value type.

Comment: @MorphingDragon: Yes, because it would require that extra constructor call I'm trying to avoid. I could do the same thing with inheritance as well.

Comment: @Matt trivial constructor calls are optimized away in any compiler worth its salt.

Comment: @MorphingDragon: Well you could have said that from the beginning. Either way, it's not optimized with `-O0`, while casting is free even with `-O0`.

Comment: Who cares what's optimized with `-O0`?

Comment: @Barry: If two things are otherwise equal, but one of them has a small advantage in one very obscure circumstance, then that very obscure circumstance (i.e. `-O0`) is what settles the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I cast the return value of _make_foo() from _foo_t to foo_t safely, compliantly, and without creating any overhead?

You definitely can't cast *safely* since you don't know that the downcast is valid. However, in this particular case, since our derived type is the same size as the base type, you can get away with:

```
template <typename T>
foo_t<T> make_foo()
{
    return static_cast<foo_t<T>&>(_make_foo());
}
```

That said, while this is something that makes sense to do in a CRTP world, I'm not sure it makes sense here.

Comment: I hadn't thought though of casting to a reference, however it doesn't work because `_make_foo()` returns a temp, which cannot be cast to a reference: `error: invalid static_cast from type ‘_foo_t’ to type ‘const foo_t<SomeObject>&’`.

Comment: In case you're wondering, I ended up settling for a templatized conversion operator in the `_foo_t`: `template <typename T> explicit operator foo_t<T>() const { return *static_cast<foo_t<T>*>(this); }`, which is similar enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize your class template `foo_t` to be able to hold any data type without depending on `_foo_t`. You can just use:

```
template <typename T> class foo_t 
{
   public:
      char data[sizeof(T)];
      T *getptr() const { return (T*)data; }
      T &getref() const { return *(T*)data; }
};

template <typename T>
foo_t<T> make_foo()
{
   return foo_t<T>();
}
```

Here's an example program that demonstrates its usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

template <typename T> class foo_t 
{
   public:
      char data[sizeof(T)];
      T *getptr() const { return (T*)data; }
      T &getref() const { return *(T*)data; }
};

template <typename T>
foo_t<T> make_foo()
{
   return foo_t<T>();
}

struct Object1
{
   int a;
   int b;
};

struct Object2
{
   int a;
   double b;
};

struct Object3
{
   double a;
   double b;
};

int main()
{
   foo_t<Object1> obj1 = make_foo<Object1>();
   new (obj1.getptr()) Object1();
   obj1.getref().a = 10;
   obj1.getref().b = 20;
   std::cout << "Object1 - a:" << obj1.getref().a << ", b: " << obj1.getref().b << std::endl;

   foo_t<Object2> obj2 = make_foo<Object2>();
   new (obj2.getptr()) Object2();
   obj2.getref().a = 10;
   obj2.getref().b = 20.35;
   std::cout << "Object2 - a:" << obj2.getref().a << ", b: " << obj2.getref().b << std::endl;

   foo_t<Object3> obj3 = make_foo<Object3>();
   new (obj3.getptr()) Object3();
   obj3.getref().a = 10.92;
   obj3.getref().b = 20.35;
   std::cout << "Object3 - a:" << obj3.getref().a << ", b: " << obj3.getref().b << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Output of the program:

```
Object1 - a:10, b: 20
Object2 - a:10, b: 20.35
Object3 - a:10.92, b: 20.35
```

**Update**

Given your comments, I think all you need is:

```
template <typename T>
class foo_t : public _foo_t
{
   public:

      // Make sure you can use all of the base class
      // constructors in this class.
      using _foo_t::_foo_t;

      T *getptr() const { return (T*)_foo_t::getptr(); }
      T &getref() const { return *(T*)_foo_t::getptr(); }
};

template <typename T>
foo_t<T> make_foo()
{
   // Construct a foo_t<T> using a _foo_t and return it.
   return foo_t<T>(_make_foo());
}
```

Comment: That's not what my class is doing. It doesn't actually hold anything, just an integer value that maps to a virtual address. It's not supposed to be a storage container. The reason for `_foo_t` is to have the bulk of the code in a library, rather than in headers, with `foo_t<T>` just being a type-safe wrapper.

Comment: Perhaps I am confused. How would `_foo_t::getptr()` know how much memory is required by `Object1` or `SomeObject`? Where would it get the memory from?

Comment: Because I did not give you my full code. I gave just enough to ask a specific question. Also, it would be `_make_foo` that requires the size.

Comment: That's the problem of posting bits and pieces of code. You can either post the full relevant code or explain what you are doing without the help of code.

Comment: I don't need help with what I'm doing in general. I was just curious about one particular detail. If I gave you all of the details, they would just distract from the question.

Comment: @Matt this is the XY problem. Tell us what you're wanting to achieve instead of latching onto this sub optimal architecture.

Comment: Well thanks for giving me the exact answer I specifically said I was not looking for.

Comment: @MorphingDragon: I did tell you exactly what I want to achieve, but you guys are trying to work around it. A straight answer would have been "What you're looking for does not exist. The best way to do this really is to use the constructor, which should not have any overhead with a reasonable compiler." Like I said, this question isn't about how to design my classes, but about **whether I can downcast a value type**.

Comment: You can't take a base class object and treat it like a derived class object in a standards compliant way. I'm guessing that is the answer you are looking for

Comment: @MorphingDragon: The idea is that since you cannot see my real code, you have no way of knowing why I want to know what I want to know. All I want is a straight answer to my simple question, not a code review.

Comment: @RSahu: "You can't take a base class object and treat it like a derived class object in a standards compliant way." Yes, that's exactly the answer I'm looking for, thanks!